# Getting alpha/opacity of a View in Android

Tags: java, android, animation, transparency, alpha

How can I get the alpha/opacity of a `View` after I've animated it?

My `fadeIn()` is below - `fadeOut()` is the same with the endpoints switched.

```
public void fadeIn(View view) {
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you to define the animations in an XML-file. The API doesn't have support for getting a specific alpha.

You can still have in mind that the opacity that your view has, is the last one you've defined; in this case, (your `fadeIn()` method), your latest opacity value is the value you passed into the `AlphaAnimation` constructor.